# Minimizing the products of variables

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming, nonconvex

**My problem**

Maximize

$$\min_{i} \{\ c_i \cdot \prod_{j \in A(i)} {x_{j}} \prod_{j \in B(i)} {y_{j}} \} $$

Subject  to

\begin{align}
&\sum_{j \in C(k)} x_{j} = 1,\ \forall k \\
&l \leq x_{j} \leq u,\ \forall j\\
&\sum_{j \in D(k)} y_{j} = 1+p,\ \forall k\\
&y_{j} \in \{1,\ p\},\ \forall j
\end{align}

where $c_i, l, u, p$ are positive constants less than 1, and sets $A, B, C, D$ are also given.

**What I have tried**

I have tried to use [`ncpol2sdpa`](http://ncpol2sdpa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to relax the polynomial programming into a semi-definite programming and call the [`sdpa`](http://sdpa.sourceforge.net/) solver to solve it.

The objective is replaced with a new variable $ \ f$, and the following constraints are added

$$\ f \leq c_i \cdot \prod x_{j} \prod y_{j}, \forall i\, .$$

Each discrete variable $y_i$ is replaced by $y_i = p \cdot (1-z_i) + z_i$, where $z_i = \{0,\ 1\}$ or equivalently, $z_i^2-z_i=0$.

However even for a small problem (5 $x$'s and 8 $y$'s), it took hours for `ncpol2sdpa` to relax and `sdpa` to solve the relaxed problem. The level of relaxation is set to be 3.

I also tried to relax the constraint on $y$ to be continues, but still quite slow.

I wonder if I did anything wrong with both tools? Or is there a better method/solver for this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to take logarithms of the objective function to simplify things?

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee I also thought about this idea. But the constraints will have exponential terms then:(